# Is there any difference between refreshing a WorkbookConnection or its ODBCConnection?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any difference between the two refresh methods to have into consideration or is it pratically the same such that either can be used?

```
Sub refresh()

  Dim workbook_connection As Excel.WorkbookConnection
  Dim odbc_connection As Excel.ODBCConnection

  Set workbook_connection = ThisWorkbook.Connections(1)
  Set odbc_connection = workbook_connection.ODBCConnection

  odbc_connection.CommandText = "..."

  ' the question is about these two lines:
  odbc_connection.Refresh
  workbook_connection.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe, not 100%, but I the WorkbookConnection contains more than one connection type, one being an ODBCConnection, so I think they do the same, but the excel version is more user friendly, again, not 100%  Have a look at the two objects in the locals window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workbook connection is an object, whereas a OBDC connection is a property of a workbook connection.

[You can read more about the details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookconnection), but think about workbook refresh as refreshing all the connections, but with OBDC you can refresh those types of connections.

Alternatively you can refresh everything very simply with the code below:

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```